# Как мне сделать так чтобы при вызове метода у меня не пропадали данные в select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть **SELECT** в котором пользователь выбирает юзера, после выводится таблица с данными.
У меня есть так же кнопка **EDIT**, которая останавливает реактивное обновление таблицы. Есть так же кнопка **CANCEL**, которая возобновляет обновление таблицы. После того как я остановил таблицу кнопкой **EDIT** и заново потом возобновляю таблицу кнопкой **CANCEL**  у меня пропадает user в **SELECT**. Дело в методе который возобновляет обновление данных. Как мне сделать так чтобы данные в **SLELECT** не пропадали после нажатия на кнопку **CANCEL**?

**SELECT**

```
  <vSelect
    :modelValue="$store.state.calculator.users"
    :options="users"
    :label="$t('Select_user_admin')"
    @input="handleUsersSelect"
    class="underlying select-gradient"
  >
  </vSelect>
```

**EDIT**

```
  <button class="btn test" @click="onClickEditButton">
      {{ $t("edit") }}
    </button>
```

**CANCEL**

```
        <v-button
          class="button-cancel"
          @upGetStatisctics="cancelOrder"
          >{{ $t("back") }}</v-button
        >
```

***Метод кнопки EDIT***

```
onClickEditButton() {
  if (this.activeTab === 1) {
    this.isEditing = true;
    clearInterval(this.timerId);
  } else if (this.activeTab === 2) {
    this.isEditingPosition = true;
    clearInterval(this.timerId);
  }
},
```

**Метод кнопки CANCEL**

```
cancelOrder() {
  if (this.activeTab === 1) {
    this.isEditing = false;
    this.handleUsersSelect();
  } else if (this.activeTab === 2) {
    this.isEditingPosition = false;
    this.handleUsersSelect();
  }
},
```

**Метод который сетит юзера**

```
async handleUsersSelect(userId) {
  clearInterval(this.timerId);
  this.$store.commit("calculator/setUserSiteAdmin", userId);

  this.timerId = setInterval(async () => {
    const marginsResponse = await this.fetchCleintTableInfoByTab({
      userId,
      url: "/admin/margins",
    });
    const positionsResponse = await this.fetchCleintTableInfoByTab({
      userId,
      url: "/admin/positions",
    });
    console.log("$store", this.$store.state.calculator.users);
    this.margins = this.convertMargins(marginsResponse);
    this.positions = this.convertPositions(positionsResponse);
  }, 2000);
},
```

Comment: Нипанятна, т.к. от жирного капса в глазах рябит, набросаны 6 кусков несвязанного кода, и вместо полезной технической информации рассказ о личных похождениях. Ясно что ты старался сделать понятнее (спасибо), но увы, получилось наоборот... рекомендую переоформить, т.к. вряд ли кто-то захочет через эти излишние препятствия пробираться к сути вoпроса. В тексте сфокусируйся на задаче/проблеме и техн.фактах, а не своих переживаниях (типа "работает так-то, проблема в том-то, желаемый результат такой-то"), ну и предоставь участникам воспроизводимый пример - это поможет, уверен.

Comment: В том что есть, не понимая как все это связано, подозрения вызывают следующие моменты: прямой бинд на стейт вьюэкса (лучше как можно скорее переделать его на геттер/компьютед); крайне усложненный код обработчиков кнопок (его желательно отрефакторить в один общий метод, заодно усилив контроль выполнения); вероятно, стоит добавить буферную переменную локального состояния, чтобы упростить  общий алгоритм (если правильно предполагаю что требуется выполнить слияние состояний после их рассинхронизации), либо вообще отделить бизнеслогику от шаблона (ну, в идеале... это эффективнее но сложнее).

Comment: Самый главный пробел в информации это сам селект - не показано на что биндится его внутренний индекс, как эта переменная состояния меняет свое значение в процессе всей этой санта-барбары с кнопками, как этот компонент оповещает об изменениях которые инициирует, и т.д.. Если компонент в принципе никак не делится своим внутренним стейтом, то надо его (компонент) править. А если делится но это не используешь - это и будет ответом (как минимум на часть вопроса, о "пропадает").